# SQL group by function to display landing page (first page) of a session

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables containing website sessions data:

- Sessions - session_id (PK), session_date, traffic_source
- PageViews - event_id (PK), session_id, timestamp, page_name

**How can I get number of sessions for a given day summarized by landing page (first page seen in the session)?**

Suppose this is  the sample data in the two tables:

**Sessions:**

```
SESSION_ID  SESSION_DATE    TRAFFIC_SOURCE
1           24-FEB-19        Google
2           23-FEB-19        Amazon
3           22-FEB-19        Clickstream
4           21-FEB-19        BloggerVlogger
5           24-FEB-19        DuckDuckGoGo
```

**Pageviews:**

```
EVENT_ID    SESSION_ID  TIMESTAMP                       PAGE_NAME
11           1          24-FEB-19 12.10.09.000000 PM    Home_page
12           2          23-FEB-19 01.10.09.000000 PM    Catalog
13           3          22-FEB-19 02.10.09.000000 PM    Shopping_Cart
14           4          21-FEB-19 03.10.09.000000 PM    Home_page
15           5          24-FEB-19 04.10.09.000000 PM    Purchase_Summary
16           5          24-FEB-19 05.10.09.000000 PM    Purchase_History
```

I tried:

```
select 
    session_date, 
    count(s.session_id) as count_of_sessions, 
    min(p.timestamp) as first_page_timestamp
from sessions s, pageviews p
where s.session_id=p.session_id
group by session_date
```

And this is the output I get:

```
SESSION_DATE    COUNT_OF_SESSIONS   FIRST_PAGE_TIMESTAMP
21-FEB-19         1                 21-FEB-19 03.10.09.000000 PM
22-FEB-19         1                 22-FEB-19 02.10.09.000000 PM
24-FEB-19         2                 24-FEB-19 04.10.09.000000 PM
24-FEB-19         1                 24-FEB-19 12.10.09.000000 PM
23-FEB-19         1                 23-FEB-19 01.10.09.000000 PM
```

If I include the `page_name` in select statement and group_by clause, it is giving me ALL the pages for that session (`Purchase_Summary` and `Purchase_History` for `session_id` 5) and I want only the first page (`Purchase Summary`).

How can I include page_name in my SQL query, when I only want to group by the session_date? Should I use something other than group by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`.  I think you want:

```
select s.*, p.*
from sessions s left join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.session_id order by p.timestamp asc) as seqnum
      from pageviews p
     ) p
     on s.session_id = p.session_id and p.seqnum = 1;
```

You can aggregate this as well:

```
select s.session_date, p.page_name,
       count(*) as count_of_sessions, 
       min(p.timestamp) as first_page_timestamp
from sessions s left join
     (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by p.session_id order by p.timestamp asc) as seqnum
      from pageviews p
     ) p
     on s.session_id = p.session_id and p.seqnum = 1
group by s.session_date, p.page_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You current logic is already pretty good. You could simply add a `NOT EXISTS` condition to your `WHERE` clause, with a correlated subquery that ensures that the current record is the first for the current session.

I assume that `event_id` can be used to sort records, if not you might want to change it to something else (`timestamp` maybe).

```
SELECT 
    s.session_date, 
    COUNT(s.session_id) as count_of_sessions, 
    MIN(p.timestamp) as first_page_timestamp
FROM sessions s
INNER JOIN pageviews p ON s.session_id = p.session_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM pageviews p1 
    WHERE p1.session_id = p.session_id AND p1.event_id < p.event_id
)
GROUP BY session_date
```

NB : always use explicit `JOIN`s instead of old-style, implicit `JOIN`s (I adapted the query accordingly).

Comment: this is a good solution and it gets the first row, but we also need to add page_name in select and group by statements in order to get the page_name.